# Как проверить подлинность данных, получаемых с ВКонтакте?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Недавно ВК запустила ["Приложения для сообществ"](https://vk.com/dev/community_apps_docs). Обычный iframe, на адрес iframe передаются гет-параметры с id юзера, и другая инфа...

Для безопасности мне нужно удостовериться, что эти гет-параметры не подделаны пользователем. В документации кажется есть решение этого:

> Среди параметров запуска передаётся sign — подпись запроса. С её помощью Вы можете удостовериться, что данные запроса не были подменены на стороне клиента.
>
> Пример кода на языке PHP для проверки подписи запроса:

```
$sign = ""; 

foreach ($request->getParams() as $key => $param) { 

    if ($key == 'hash' || $key == 'sign') continue; 

    $sign .=$param; 

} 

$secret = 'SECRET_KEY'; 

$sig = $secret ? hash_hmac('sha256', $sign, $secret) : "";
```

Этот код создает переменную $sign, потом пробегается по всем гет параметрам, пропуская hash и sign, а остальные записывает в $sign. Далее в $sig записывается sha256 значений гет параметров, c использованием ключа из $secret; Я все сделал также, но при сравнении $sig и гет-параметра sign строки не совпадают. Я что-то не так сделал?

Comment: *Я все сделал также* -- `SECRET_KEY`-то заменили на свой, я надеюсь? А то из вопроса это не очевидно.

Comment: Да, конечно изменил, из настроек приложения

Comment: Тут может быть много разных тонкостей, возьмите сниффер и посмотрите в каком месте расхождения. Чаще всего проблема в кодировке, например берут hash от Unicode строки

Answer (score 0):

## Не совпадают хэши, что делать ?

---

Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой.

Решение проблемы легко.

Разбираем `URL` и указываем константу `PHP_URL_QUERY`.

```
$url = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$parsed_url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

Константа `PHP_URL_QUERY` означает что мы "вытаскиваем" все после знака `?`

После разбиваем на ассоциативный массив содержимое `$parsed_url` функцией `parse_str`.

```
parse_str($parsed_url,$request);
```

Теперь в переменной `$request` хранится ассоциативный массив, которую мы будем прогонять через цикл(который был показан в документации).

```
$sign = ""; 
foreach ($request as $key => $param) { 

    if ($key == 'hash' || $key == 'sign') continue; 

    $sign .=$param; 

} 
$secret = 'Защищенный_Ключ'; 
$sig = $secret ? hash_hmac('sha256', $sign, $secret) : ""; 
$result = ($sig === $_GET['sign']) ? "Сходятся" : "Не сходятся";
```

### Итог

---

[image: Результат]